# Nothing Happens with fluid simulation

Tags: physics, eevee-render-engine, fluid-simulation, object-mode

[image]

I was learning from CG Geek's animation tutorial from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZBHS1tTE6s) at 8:45. When I played the animation, nothing happened at all to my creation, no signs of high viscous water trickling down the sphere.

Does anyone know what went missing or wrong? If you want me to add the file for further investigation please tell me how to attach one here in this post.

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/ and put a link to the file in your question.

Comment: you may also want to include a screen-cap of the fluid settings you have in your domain.  There are also gotchas related to collision objects, so include a screenshot of your collision settings on the sphere.  In MS-Windows you can use the "Snipping Tool" for such a screen-cap.

Comment: And in Blender you can save an image of the whole screen via the Window > Save screenshot menu or just one editor window via the Screenshot (Editor) entry. - Select that option then click on the window you want to save.

Comment: For the Domain, under Cache > Type, you need to click on Replay, then play the animation. If it still doesn't work, as John says, please share your file

Comment: Hey John I just added the picture

Comment: @moonboots here's the file: 
https://pasteall.org/media/0/d/0db69740d7326af81fd70cf72e769621.blend

Comment: it works for me, you need to make the fluid object visible and also make sure that you've pressed on the Cache > Type > Replay option of the Domain

Comment: I can find no fluid "supplies" in your objects in the domain.   You would need to have a Flow type of Fluid object, either a Geometry (liquid at time 0) or an Inflow (continuous throughout frames).   Also for your collision objects the 0.02 surface thickness may prove to be too thin.  I've found < 0.5 to have the object ignored.

Comment: where's the cache @moonboots (I'm so sorry lmao)

Comment: Select the domain and go into the Physics panel > Cache

Comment: oh ok thanks @moonboots

Comment: Wait @james_t, you're saying that the thickness is too thin to the extent it won't show the fluid simulation?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about not seeing the Cube.fluid object that is an inflow enabled only during frame 40.

If I look in viewport shading mode *Wireframe* I see the liquid simulation just fine, as mentioned by @moonboots:

[image]

So, you have a rendering/materials problem, not a simulation problem.

What I would do is start with a Cube in an new session, and use the Object >> Quick Effects, to add a liquid simulation to compare.

Most important issue: I enabled the Mesh property in your domain.  I'm not sure anything renders without it.

So I added a rather trivial material to your domain to get you started.   Here's a resulting render in Eevee, but I use Cycles for fluid for more realism:

[image]

Here is your file with my changes:  [image]

If you find this useful, please check the mark at top-left of my answer (so I get credit and others find this easier).

Comment: It's still not showing for some reason, should I hide the cube fluid?

Comment: @M4GN3TIC_ -- definitely look at what I did in my example blend file I included in my answer.  I "Disable in Render" the "Cube.fluid" object, if not you'd see the original cube and not the fluid emitting from the original cube.  An alternative is to apply a "clear" material (Transparent BSDF to Surface output) to the object that is the Flow Liquid Emitter.  These 3d studios certainly have a long, steep learning curve -- persist and conquer!